# How to create Composite Primary Key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working with **SQLAlchemy** in **python**.
So, there is this table called **Options** with two columns that are **trackerId** and **name** in a database.

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Options(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Options'

    trackerId = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

Assume that I have imported the required stuff and everything is well initialised.
Now how do I create a composite Primary key on both of the fields?

### Edit1

Actually the **trackerId** has a Foreign Key

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Options(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Options'

    trackerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Tracker.trackerId"))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want an auto-incrementing key as your primary key? It would make many thing much easier.

Comment: Yes, actually there will be records with same **trackerId** but different **name** ; and some records with different **trackerid** but same **name**. So I wanted to have a composite key.

Comment: How would that stop you from having an auto-increment field (additionally)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that **trackerId** has a Foreign Key. It is getting the **trackerId** from the **Tracker** table.

Comment: Won't change anything.

Comment: I didn't what you mean.